# Marshaling SafeHandles from unmanaged to managed

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

In a native dll wrapper I'm writing, I've just replaced all usages of IntPtr (to marshal handles) with SafeHandles. I was under the impression that a properly written SafeHandle type was interchangeable with IntPtr in this way.

However, my Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate calls are now throwing an exception:

```
Cannot marshal 'parameter #n': SafeHandles cannot be marshaled from unmanaged to managed.
```

The callback contain a handle in the argument list, and so the delegate contains a SafeHandle in its place (instead of an IntPtr as before). So can I just not do this? If so, what are my options for using SafeHandles, given that I need to marshal callbacks?

Here's an edited example of the native dll header:

```
struct aType aType;
typedef void (*CallBackType)(aType*, int);
aType* create(); // Must be released
void   release(aType* instance);
int    doSomething(aType* instance, int argumnet);
void   setCallback(CallbackType func);
```

The bit that is causing me trouble is the callback. The C# side looked like this:

```
delegate void CallBackType(IntPtr instance, int argument);
```

Then:

```
var funcPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del = new CallbackType(somefunc)):

NativeFunction.setCallback(funcPtr)
```

This works fine, and always had done. However, I wanted to move from IntPtr for manaaging the handle to safehandle, and read that it was a drop in replacement. However, replacing IntPtr with a SafeHandle subclass in the above C# code causes the reported exception:

```
 delegate void CallBackType(MySafeHandle instance, int argument);
```

Comment: Isn't SafeHandle a .NET-side (as opposed to native) concept? What do your interop declarations look like?

Comment: SafeHandle is indeed a .NETside concept (as is IntPtr). Will add more detail to my original question.

Comment: SafeHandle is an abstract class.  There isn't any way that the pinvoke marshaller could pick the correct derived class type from the declaration, all it has is an IntPtr.

Comment: Sorry, I should write MySafeHandle. Obviously, I had to implement my own SafeHandle, with an appropriate Release override. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 8):

The error message is misleading. It's *100% possible* to marshal safehandles from unmanaged to managed because that is how SafeHandles are *supposed to be created*. See how CreateFile is defined for instance:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, 
    FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs,
    FileMode dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

The reason the compiler is generating an error messages is really the way you declare the *delegate*. I made the same mistake as you and tried to use MySafeHandle type as a delegate parameter, when I declared my callback delegate (here, unmanaged code is going to call back to your managed code):

```
delegate void TimerCallback(IntPtr pCallbackInstance, IntPtr context, MySafeHandle ptpTimer);
```

For which I got the exact same error message as you have. However, once I changed my delegate signature to IntPtr, the error disappears, so we can see our naiive intuition is incorrect...

```
delegate void TimerCallback(IntPtr pCallbackInstance, IntPtr context, IntPtr ptpTimer);
```

See, **voila, the error is gone**! Now we just have to work out how to use the IntPtr that comes into the delegate to look up the correct MySafeHandle object...!

Once I figured out what change fixed the error, I could also come up with a theory as to *why* it fixes the error.

The theory: (unverified)

The reason you have to use IntPtr in the delegate signature is that SafeHandles are *special*. Whenever you marshal as a SafeHandle, the CLR marshaller automatically converts an opaque IntPtr handle into a *new CLR SafeHandle object* which *owns* the HANDLE in question. (Note that SafeHandles are objects, not structs!)

If you created a new owner object for the OS HANDLE every time the delegate was called, you would soon be in very big trouble, because your object would get garbage collected once you return from the delegate!

So I guess perhaps the compiler is merely trying to save us from this mistake - in its own confusingly worded way?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm...just thinking out loud, but I think you'll have to effect some sort of inter-wrapper; `SafeHandle` works with the P/invoke implementation during basic marshalling, but not "manual marshalling", like you're doing here...try something like this, maybe?

```
internal delegate void InnerCallbackType(IntPtr instance, int argument);
public delegate void MyCallBackType(MySafeHandle instance, int argument);

public void SetCallback(Action<MySafeHandle, int> someFunc) 
{
    InnerCallbackType innerFunc = (rawHandle, rawArg) => 
    {
        someFunc(new MySafeHandle(rawHandle, true), rawArg);
    };
    var funcPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(innerFunc);
    NativeFunction.setCallback(funcPtr);
}
```

That way, you'd still retain your "type safety" wrt the `SafeHandle` usage, while letting you handle the marshalling the way you want to...

Comment: I suppose the difficulty then becomes that the callback to my library is made with an IntPtr rather than the MySafeHandle - so I'd need to maintain some sort of cache dictionary of all MySafeHandles in order to retrieve the right one, given an IntPtr.

Comment: @TomDavies ugh, didn't think of that...I mean, it'd be a trivial thing to do, but annoying...suppose you could bake the 'cache' into your `SafeHandle` class, maybe even with an `implicit operator` to convert to/from `IntPtr`...

Comment: You probably also need to implement it using a weak dictionary - so that it doesn't prevent your safe handle objects from being garbage collected and finalized once you are finished using them.

Comment: It's also possible instead of using a weak dictionary to use weak GC Handles, and pass the int value of those...

Answer (score 1):

It's **possible** with some extra steps to turn `IntPtr` to `MySafeHandle` **without proxy**-ing the delegate into another **using ICustomMarshaler**.

> delegate void CallBackType(MySafeHandle instance, int argument);

so let's do some fancy stuph with it:

pretend we pass the delegate like this to unmanaged environment with __cdecl calling convention (just for the example):

```
[DllImport("some.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void setCallback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] CallBackType callBackType);
```

and then we want decorate our delegate:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] // depends on unmanaged implementation, but for the example sake
delegate void CallBackType([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MyCustomMarshaler))] MySafeHandle instance, int argument);
```

and finally the **ICustomMarshaler** implementation:

```
public sealed class MyCustomMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    private static MyCustomMarshaler _instance = new MyCustomMarshaler();

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object o)
    {
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr ptr)
    {
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return IntPtr.Size;
    }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object o)
    {
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        return new MySafeHandle()
        {
            handle = ptr
        };
    }

    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string s)
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

I posted the answer because I couldn't find anything about it on the internet (whenever it's safe or not, or why isn't marshaling automatically turns IntPtr to SafeHandle).